# MAPI_E_NO_ACCESS error setting RDOPstStore property

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I'm attempting to set (actually clear) the PR_PST_PASSWORD property on a PST file using Redemption thusly:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOPstStore store = session.LogonPstStore(sourcePstPath,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,password);
Int32 PR_PST_PASSWORD = 0x67ff0003;
store.Fields[PR_PST_PASSWORD] = 0x00000000;
```

That last line throws this exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024891
Message=Error in HrSetOneProp: MAPI_E_NO_ACCESS
```

Is there a way I can set this property?

Comment: `Are you running this using `Multiple Threads`...? if so then this sounds like the problem and or issue..

Comment: No, single threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, PST password needs to be supplied when the PST service is configured when a PST store is being added. It is definitely not stored as a property on the store itself.

Secondly, I have never seen `0x67ff0003` property. I know of `PR_FAIMsgFolderPropTagArray` and `PR_ServerName` properties, but they are of type `PT_BINARY` (`0x67FF0102`), not `PT_LONG`.

Comment: Per MSDN the PidTagPstPassword property stores the hash of the password text (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385916(v=office.12).aspx). Per the ASPOSE.Email documentation (http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailnet/Check+if+a+PST+is+password+protected) I can query this property to tell if it is password protected or not. I need to clear this property so a process can run downstream on the pst file. Is there a way to clear this with Redemption? Thanks Dmitry.

Comment: That property is not exposed on the IMsgStore MAPI object. It is only stored in the PST file itself. Since Aspose does not use MAPI to access PST files, they are free to expose it as a separate property. MSPST provider does not do that - you can only change the password when the PST is being added to the profile - MSPST provider lets you specify the old and new passwords.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. you say "you can only change the password when the PST is being added to the profile" - is there a way I can do that with Redemption?

Comment: Redemption does not explicitly support that, but you call RDOSession.Stores.AddPstStoreWithPassword with the old password, remove the store, then try to call AddPstStoreWithPassword with the new password.